# Deny access to only one user to a file

Tags: linux, permissions

I recently had this question at a test for a Linux certification.
How do you do this?

1. Copy file `/etc/fstab` to `/tmp/fstab_bck` and make sure it's owned by root and group is root.

   I know how to do this.
2. Make sure user X does not have access.
3. Make sure user Y has access to view.
   Make sure that all other newly created users have access to view this file.

Comment: Have a look at POSIX ACL (access control lists, google). Only works on filesystems that support them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish requirements 2 and 3, you need to use ACLs in addition to normal chmod permissions:

```
chmod o+r /tmp/fstab_bck
setfacl -m u:userx:000 /tmp/fstab_bck
```

No need to write an ACL for User Y, since User Y is part of "other" users.

Answer (score 0):

While "2." is trivial (just don't put X into group "root", which you'd never do, anyways), 3. is impossible only with the original POSIX owner/group/rest permission system.

Luckily, ACLs have been around for ages, so that's probably what your certification wants you to [learn at least rudimentarily](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-access-control-lists).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i was suspecting ACL's however, none of the documentation or study guide even mention ACL. I thought there would be something that could be acomplished by regular permissions.